# How to remove border around Gtk Widgets and Window?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm making a Gtk.Window using PyGi Gtk3 and It adds an annoying border around widgets and the main window:

[image: Gtk.Window border example]

The border is this grey border between the two images and in the outside of the window. Anyone knows how to completely remove it? So the two images could be seamless joint together.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#encoding:utf-8


from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk


class TestMainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Test Window")
        self.set_resizable(False)

        self.box = Gtk.Box(orientation='vertical')
        self.add(self.box)

        self.album_cover = Gtk.Image()
        self.album_cover.set_from_file('../reference/album-cover.jpg')
        self.box.pack_start(self.album_cover, True, True, 0)

        self.album_cover2 = Gtk.Image()
        self.album_cover2.set_from_file('../reference/album-cover.jpg')
        self.box.pack_end(self.album_cover2, True, True, 0)


def main():
    win = TestMainWindow()
    win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try at setting the "margins" property inherited from GtkWidget to FALSE. In C this is done using g_object_set.

Comment: Hi, could you explain this a bit more? I've already tried using `self.set_border_width(0)` in the windows with no effect. It's this the same or is different?

Comment: I just tested your code, and in fact I have no grey area using the very same code you use. So either you're using some kind of tweaked theme, or more probably the grey area belongs to the image. BTW, no, set_border_width in unrelated to the margins property. "margin" is a GtkWidget property. You may set its value using `self.album_cover.set_property("margin", 0)`, but default value is already 0, so I think it will change nothing. Read http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/objects.html#properties to know how to manipulate properties.

Comment: I'm using Awesome WM. In Awesome I have the grey area, but, later, I've tried it on a Elementary OS environment, and the grey area disapears. Awesome doesn't use window composition, so I have discarded it. What's left? It's related to the theme then? Because I have apps that doesn't have this border, so there may be a way to disable it.

And thank you so much for your help.

Comment: BTW,when I said I had no grey borders, my test configuration was GNOME 3.6 + default Adwaita theme.